# Java - Servlet, Carry login information throughout project (session bean)

Tags: java, jsp, session, netbeans, javabeans

I have a login servlet, it works fine. But I would like for multiple servlets to be able to access the userID, valid, & facultyCB values to do different functions. I know the best way is with a session, can some1 please provide an example of writing, and calling from a session using my Login Servlet and ViewRegisteredCoursesServlet. If an object(bean) is stored with:

```
session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser", user);
```

How can you get different values from this in a servlet? EX. userId & facultyCB.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser");
```

Also, from what I understand the session needs to be forwarded (something thats not an option as depending on which nav bar is clicked a diff servlet is called). Correct?

LoginServlet:

```
    LoginBean user = new LoginBean();

    try {
        String checkBox = request.getParameter("facultyCB");

        user.setID(request.getParameter("id"));
        user.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

        if (checkBox != null) {
            user.setFacultyCB(true);
        } else {
            user.setFacultyCB(false);
        }

        user = LoginDAO.login(user);

        if (user.isValid()) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            if (checkBox != null) {
                user.setFacultyCB(true);
            } else {
                user.setFacultyCB(false);
            }

            session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser", user);
            response.sendRedirect("success_login.jsp"); //logged-in page

        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("invalid_login.jsp"); //error page 
        }
```

ViewRegisteredCoursesServlet:

```
String userID = "100000001";

    //Created code to determine term based on course dates
    String year = "2012";
    String term = "FALL";

    try {

        List<RegisteredCoursesBean> registeredCoursesArray = ViewRegisteredCoursesDAO.viewRegisteredCourses(userID, year, term);

        request.setAttribute("registeredCoursesBean", registeredCoursesArray);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("registered_courses.jsp").forward(request, response);

    } catch (Throwable theException) {
        System.out.println(theException);
    }
```

LoginBean:

```
private String id;
private String password;
private boolean facultyCB;
public boolean valid;
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I think I got it on my own. I just pass the 3 values I want separately. Is there a way to pass a bean into a session, and then get the values in another servlet?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to Store a bean in and access it in other servlets. the best way you can do is to store that bean inside the session object.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("BEANNAMEHERE", yourBeanObjectHere);
```

Accessing it in other servlets

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
YourBeanObject myBean =  (YourBeanObjectClass) session.getAttribute("BEANNAMEHERE");
```

**SIDE NOTE**
I don't think it is a good idea to store the users Login information inside the session, perhaps just store he's ID and use that ID to retrieve his data from the database.